# Anonymous users publishing my site with blank content

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-7, content-type, anonymous

Several times a day Anonymous users create content and publish it on my drupal site. The content is blank, not even clickable. I have my login page redirect to my ldap login so users can't even create accounts in the first place. Do you know how i can stop this? I feel it will fill my site up and it is very hard to navigate though all the content. Thanks.

Image of anonymous content:
http://s16.postimg.org/4wy09uxno/content.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could change the content permissions so that anonymous users can't create content, this would be the easiest although you might want to retain that option for legitimate users. In which case you could try making fields mandatory?

Comment: I have it set already to anonymous users can not create content. I can't have every field be mandatory for some content types because of the nature of the content. Either way, they seem to be making content without any fields of information.

Comment: Wow! This is strange. Have you checked the report logs? Can you verify if this is coming from an external IP address or if it's being done by the system?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks so much! I checked the report logs and there were two feeds importers scheduling to import every 30 mins which was causing all the blank content from being added. Thanks again!